# Error in browsing file c++

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to browse file using windows application form in c++ Visual Studio 2010. This code gives the following errors. Can anyone help solving the problem

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

      Stream^ myStream;
      OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

      openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
      openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
      openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
      openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

      if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
      {
            if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
                myStream->Close();
            }
      }

}
```

Error   1   error C2065: 'Stream' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\

Error   2   error C2065: 'myStream' : undeclared identifier

Error   3   error C2065: 'myStream' : undeclared identifier

Error   4   error C2065: 'myStream' : undeclared identifier

Error   5   error C2227: left of '->Close' must point

Comment: What do you think '^' means in C++?

Comment: i dont know i have taken this code from one the post in this forum

Comment: This code is not C++.

Comment: You people are being deliberately obtuse.  This is C++/CLI and this information was easy to glean from the mention of VS, reference to Windows Forms and the use of the caret `^`.  The question might not be the best, but if you're not here to help, why log on at all?

Comment: Can you tell me why this code gives me the above mentioned errors.

Comment: @user2740528 I'm not home right now so I can't test this but you seem to be missing a reference to the `System.IO` namespace.  Trying adding `using namespace System::IO;` at the top of your code file.

Comment: thanks alot my problem is solved i was making the same mistake u mentioned. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of code file this has removed my error.

using namespace system::IO